# Head nod detection

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, video-processing, deep-learning

I am working on a research project that consists of many problems of computer vision. One of the problems currently is as follows.

Problem description: There is a group of people in a hall (a classroom scenario, perhaps) where cameras are installed in vantage locations so as to be able to detect each face in the room. Under this constant surveillance, I need to figure out a technique (learning algorithm, perhaps) to detect head nodding and possibly track their line of sight too.

How may I approach this problem?

Comment: So you are looking for a head detector, right? Have you seen the following study?
http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07917

Comment: Thanks, Saeed, but my problem is more complex than just head detection. It is head nod detection. I need my system to detect when people nod their heads.

Comment: start with head detection & tracking. once you got head tracking you'll be able to gain more insights regarding the tools needed for nod detection. It may be that a simple rule (e.g. head goes down and up by at least x pixels in less than y frames) will do.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on getting a dataset now.